# Taking time to boot Freya

Tags: release-freya, boot

After some days of working. i have installed , chrome, php, apache, mysql, teamviewer, skype, and few small apps. mine Freya takes time to boot. What is the reason for the delay. and anything i can do to decrease the boot time.

Answer (score 2):

- Control Startup Applications:

  The less programs you have loading on bootup, the faster your system should be. You can control these startup applications from the system settings --> applications --> startup

  [image: Imgur]
  (I don't have many apps to show )

---

- Install `BootUp-Manager` from software center to disable any un-necessary services.

---

- Use `bootchart` to produce detailed graphs of what takes time during boot.
  Install it from software center. After installation, reboot your system, the bootchart is in `/var/log/bootchart` as a `.png` file. It might help in deciding what to remove (or disable).

Further references:

[How To Cut Your Linux PC’s Boot Time in Half With E4rat](http://www.howtogeek.com/69753/how-to-cut-your-linux-pcs-boot-time-in-half-with-e4rat/)

From comment by [@elmato](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/137/elmato)

> If you follow that e4rat tutorial you may hit a roadblock when you are attempting to boot into `single` user mode (by appending single to the end of the boot option string). If you find you get no prompt, use `rw init=/bin/bash` instead of `single`.

[6 Ways to Speed Up Your PC](http://www.howtogeek.com/115797/6-ways-to-speed-up-ubuntu/)

Comment: Let me check it

Comment: Just a note: If you follow that e4rat tutorial you may hit a roadblock when you are attempting to boot into single user mode (by appending `single` to the end of the boot option string). If you find you get no prompt, use `rw init=/bin/bash` instead of `single`.

Comment: Can I incorporate that into answer? @elmato

Comment: @Ravan Do you use e4rat.My laptop is taking about one minute to boot freya while Windows 10 boots in 25 seconds (5400rpm HDD, UEFI). I am wondering if it will break freya

Comment: @Ravan So can e4rat speed up the boot for my HDD (haven't yet got a SSD). Is it safe to try